# Automatically add links into UITextView when they begin with http or https

Tags: swift, hyperlink, uitextview

[This answer provides a class that automatically adds links in an UITextView when they begin with 'www'.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41520898/5807658) Unfortunately I cannot use that because all of the links I need to add begin with either http or https. The links are to attributions so I cannot change the link to starting with 'www'. Is there a way to automatically add links into the UITextView when they begin with http or https? If not what is my best option for adding many links into an UITextView?

Comment: Why don't you just modify the linked answer to search for strings starting with "http" or "https" instead of "www"?

Comment: @nathan Is there a way to change the linked answer to also make the links blue?