# Add Hyperlink to Storyboard using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, hyperlink

I would like to add a link to my main story board but can't seem to find a way to do it.  I've seen a post detailing how to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425096/how-to-display-clickable-links-in-uitextview/34425135) it but it seems the Behavior options are different and there aren't any Detection options.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Running the latest xcode and iOS I can see the options detailed in the link you mentioned. They are now called "Data Detectors" but they are still directly under "Behavior"

Comment: For a Label the only Behavior options I see are Enabled and Highlighted; no Detection or Data Detectors.  For a TextField there isn't Behavior or Detection options at all in the attribute inspector but there is a Content Type URL under Text Input Traits however tapping it does nothing.  Perhaps I'm using the wrong field type?  XCode 9.4.1, iOS 10.13.6

Comment: As mentioned in the link you sent, these options are only available on a textView. It is meant for large bodies of text with links embedded. If you want a simple hyperlink on its own, you can just use a label, make the text blue and add a tap gesture to it

Comment: If the whole text a link? If no, don't use a `UILabel`, use a `UITextView`. If yes, you can use a `UILabel`, but you'll have to add a tap gesture.

Comment: Adding the tap gesture to a Label worked perfectly.  Why was this question down voted?

Comment: What I found that is interesting is that I have 2 links in a StackView now and if I miss-tap or tap anywhere in the view that isn't the first link, the 2nd link's action is fired even though I'm not taping anywhere near it.

Comment: So this is a problem now.  I have a stack view with a link, labels, list view and a contact link.  No matter where I tap in the view, even in the list view, if its not the first link that is tapped the last link (contact) is fired.  I can't make a selection from the table.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestions adding a tap gesture to a Label implements a simple hyperlink.  Here's the code I used in the ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var contactUrl:  UIView!

var webView = WebViewClient()


@objc func contactUrlTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let myURL = URL(string: "https://google.com")

    let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL)

    webView.load(myRequest)
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let contactUrlAction = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.contactUrlTapped(_:)))
    contactUrl.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    contactUrl.addGestureRecognizer(contactUrlAction)
}
```